# How can i get rid of 0^n in my output?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

i reworked my question, because i realized that it wasn't clear enough

here is my minimal example:

```
x[n_, m_, k_] := (n - m)^k
x[n, n, k]
```

My output is: 0^k 
Obviously i want mathematica to give me back 0, so that in future steps it can cancel things out or recognize that x[n,n,k]=0 for all n.

PS: Sorry for this super simple question.

Comment: Note that it cannot solve the equivalent system `Solve[{n > 0, n \[Element] Integers}, {n}]`.  Try `Reduce` instead: `Reduce[{0^n == 0, n > 0, n \[Element] Integers}, {n}]`. (Or `Reduce[{0^n == 0}, {n}]`.)

Comment: It might be that what you're looking for is the use of assumptions in `Simplify`: `Simplify[0^n == 0, n > 0 && n \[Element] Integers]`.

Comment: Thank you so far. Can you also tell me how i can get rid of the x[n_]=0^n and get x[n_]=0 instead. I have a larger operation before and i would like mathematica to cancel the zeroes on its own.

Comment: I would probably add a special definition: `x[n_, n_, k_] := 0` or `x[n_, m_, k_] /; n == m := 0`. It's best if this precedes the more general definition.  Alternatively, one could just use `x[n_, m_, k_] := Simplify[(n-m)^k, k > 0]`, but it calls `Simplify`.  If the arguments ever happen to be complicated, it might waste a lot of time.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - -sorry, I was working on my answer and didn't see your final comment, which is substantially the same. I will delete if you want to answer.

Comment: @bills No problem. I was confused whether the objective concerned solving (now deleted from the question though it remains in the tags), simplifying, or defining functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Mathematica to simplify using appropriate assumptions:

```
x[n_, m_, k_] := (n - m)^k
FullSimplify[x[n, n, k], Assumptions -> {k > 0}]
0
```

Note that k cannot be negative (or else the answer is infinity).

Comment: Thx so much. I totally forgot to set it positve.